# PyQt5 crashes whilst trying to load an PNG image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm just starting out writing a program with the `PyQt5` gui framework. I have a file, `resource_loader.py`, which is responsible for loading images etc.

**The problem**

Python crashes at the line where the image is loaded. I'm using IDLE (3.5) and after I run the program there is no output except for:

`=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================`

**Code** - pretty much copy/pasted from a tutorial, file is called `resource_loader.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import os
file_image = QtGui.QPixmap("file.png")
```

**Things I've tried**

- `file.png` definitely is in the same directory as `resource_loader.py`
- Changing up the variable names, just in case.
- Moving the file to a location with no spaces in the path

**Extra information**

- I am running `resource_loader.py` directly
- I am using Linux Mint (18.3) Xfce if that's any use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to place your code within a `QApplication` instance as follows:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

file_image = QtGui.QPixmap("file.png")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does that mean that it's not possible to have a `resource_loader.py`?

Comment: @Jachdich If it is to be used within another file/application, then I don't think so.

Comment: OK, that's not too big of a deal. Anyway, thanks for the help.